# SyntaxHighlighter BBCode PHP

Tags: php, regex, syntax-highlighting, bbcode

I'm having some problems with the BBCode I created to use with the [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)

```
function bb_parse_code($str) {
    while (preg_match_all('`\[(code)=?(.*?)\]([\s\S]*)\[/code\]`', $str, $matches)) foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $match) {
        list($tag, $param, $innertext) = array($matches[1][$key], $matches[2][$key], $matches[3][$key]); 
        switch ($tag) {
            case 'code': $replacement = '<pre class="brush: '.$param.'">'.str_replace("    ", " ", str_replace(array("<br>", "<br />"), "\n", $innertext))."</pre>"; break;

        }
        $str = str_replace($match, $replacement, $str);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

And I have the bbcode:

```
[b]bold[/b]
[u]underlined[/u]
[code=js]function (lol) {
alert(lol);
}[/code]
[b]bold2[/b]
[code=php]
<? echo 'lol' ?>
[/code]
```

Which returns this:
[image: BBCode]

I know the problem is on the `([\s\S]*)` of the regex that allows any character, but how do to make the code work with line breaks?

Comment: For simple cases you may be able to get away with `(.*?)`, which is an ungreedy match for anything.

Comment: but `.*?` doesn't work with like breaks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following pattern:

```
`\[(code)=?(.*?)\](.*?)\[/code\]`s
```

A couple of changes:

- The switch to `.*?` to [make the quantifier lazy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php).
- The `s` modifier at the end, which causes `.` to [match new lines too](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).